# Update query not making full use of index in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `posted_on` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `status` enum('pending','complete','error') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  `body` blob NOT NULL,
  `process_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `acquired_on` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `acquiredon` (`acquired_on`),
  KEY `type_status_processid_postedon` (`type`,`status`,`process_id`,`posted_on`) USING BTREE
);
```

When I do a select on this table, it makes proper/full use of the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM `queue`
FORCE INDEX (`type_status_processid_postedon`)
WHERE type = 1
AND `status` = 'pending'
AND `process_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `posted_on` ASC
LIMIT 1;

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | queue | NULL       | ref  | type_status_processid_postedon | type_status_processid_postedon | 10      | const,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

And yet, when I do the same query as an `UPDATE`, the index is not fully used.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE `queue`
FORCE INDEX(`type_status_processid_postedon`)
SET `process_id` = 1
WHERE `type` = 1
AND `status` = 'pending'
AND `process_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `posted_on` ASC
LIMIT 1;

+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | queue | NULL       | range | type_status_processid_postedon | type_status_processid_postedon | 10      | const,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

The update does a filesort. What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe because you're modifying one of the columns in the index.

Comment: But the index is used to locate the rows to be updated. The update happens *after* the lookup, so the index should still be used the same as a select (I would have thought at least).

Comment: But as it's doing the assignments, the contents of the index changes out from under it. Try changing the query to `SET acquired_on = ...` and see if that changes it.

Comment: Same result. `Using where; Using filesort`